# Check if process user is an administrator c++

Tags: c++, process

I want to get the process's user name and check if it is a local administrator . Or check directly if the current procees user is a local administrator

Comment: Which OS? It probably makes a difference...

Comment: [http://vcfaq.mvps.org/sdk/21.htm](http://vcfaq.mvps.org/sdk/21.htm) [How To Determine Whether a Thread Is Running in User Context of Local Administrator Account](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q118626/) These links might help [for Windows].

Comment: C++ has no notion of 'administrator'. Any solution would be via a platform specific library. What platform are you using?

Comment: "local administrator" is most likely on Windows.

Comment: helpful links but very long is there no shorter and easier way to get the user's name once I have the user's name I can check if it's in the desired local administrator group

Comment: If you just want to get the username, you can use WINAPI GetUserName ==> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724432(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I'm running - Windows OS

Answer (score 3):

Get the current username with **GetUserName()**, then call [NetUserGetInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370654%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the server name (NULL for local) and username you just got. Pass it a [USER_INFO_1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371109%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure, and then access **usri1_priv** in the structure. If the value is *USER_PRIV_ADMIN*, then you'll know that the username is an admin.

Answer (score 2):

Tested on Windows XP SP3, Windows 7 32 bit and 64 bit with admin user and non-admin user.
Code ported from equivalent C# and uses ATL windows security wrapper classes.

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlsecurity.h>

// The function returns true if the user who is running the
// application is a member of the Administrators group,
// which does not necessarily mean the process has admin privileges.
bool IsAdministrator(HRESULT &rHr)
{
    bool bIsAdmin = false;

    try
    {
        // Open the access token of the current process.
        ATL::CAccessToken aToken;
        if (!aToken.GetProcessToken(TOKEN_QUERY))
        {
            throw MAKE_SCODE(SEVERITY_ERROR, FACILITY_WIN32,
                ::GetLastError());
        }


        // Query for the access token's group information.
        ATL::CTokenGroups groups;
        if (!aToken.GetGroups(&groups))
        {
            throw MAKE_SCODE(SEVERITY_ERROR, FACILITY_WIN32,
                ::GetLastError());
        }

        // Iterate through the access token's groups
        // looking for a match against the builtin admins group.
        ATL::CSid::CSidArray groupSids;
        ATL::CAtlArray<DWORD> groupAttribs;
        groups.GetSidsAndAttributes(&groupSids, &groupAttribs);
        for (UINT i = 0; !bIsAdmin && i < groupSids.GetCount(); ++i)
        {
            bIsAdmin = groupSids.GetAt(i) == ATL::Sids::Admins();
        }
        rHr = S_OK;
    }
    catch (HRESULT hr)
    {
        rHr = hr;
    }

    return bIsAdmin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're on a Window OS there's a shell function: *IsUserAnAdmin*

See [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776463.aspx)

This article does suggest rolling your own function though, use *CheckTokenMembership*. There is even a code example to help you along.

Comment: thanks! but all I got is the logged on user I'M looking for a way to get the user wjo runs a service and check if it is a local administrator

Comment: I'm not sure where you are coming from. But I'm willing to help. Some more background on what you're ultimately trying to achieve may help me.
Is this service something you have written? If so you can apply security during installation to allow/deny users (and/or groups) to start or stop the service, if this is what you are after?
Generally windows services are not run as the user that started them. By default the system account is used as the account a service is run under but this can be configured to be any user you wish. The service threads may then impersonate users as they wish.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but just to point out, this only works up to windows Vista, So for windows 7, 8 and 10 this feature will not work.