# How do I check if my program is running under admin privileges via C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, batch-file, admin, elevated-privileges

How do I check if my C++ program is running with admin privileges?

I did it in this manner for batch

```
set fold=%random%

mkdir "C:\Windows\%fold%"

if errorlevel 1 (

goto Tag1

)

goto Tag2
```

But I cannot use the same thing for C++ because I do not know how to transfer value of %random% that is variable 1 to variable 2 that is %fold% and also, I do not know if there is error level for C++.

Can anyone help me in this case or is there any way to check if my program is running with admin privileges?

Comment: Have a look at this. C# I know but the principles are the same:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509292/how-can-i-tell-if-my-process-is-running-as-administrator

Comment: Your batch file is awful. Spraying folders into the system directories. Yuch! Don't do it that way!!

Comment: We also have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046097/how-to-check-if-a-process-has-the-administrative-rights and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546643/how-do-i-check-if-my-program-is-ran-by-user-as-administrator-vista-win7-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981171/check-if-process-user-is-an-administrator-c and hundreds more. Please don't treat Stack Overflow as a replacement for web search. Always search first.

Comment: It's just for testing.
If not elevated, no folder will be created.
If elevated, later the created folder will be deleted. 
@DavidHeffernan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the OpenProcessToken / [GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) pair: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8196291/3235496

An alternative is the [AccessCheck](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/118626/en-us) function.

Last the [IsUserAnAdmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function: it's simple but deprecated (available from Windows XP/Windows Server 2003).

Anyway why are you checking? Trying could be a good strategy: if it works, you have sufficient rights (possibly a subset of Admin rights).

PS

Just out of curiosity... the C++ translation of your batch file should be based on the [CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. If it fails check the extended error information via [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (return code `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`). But, as David Heffernan says, spraying folders into the system directories isn't a great idea.

Comment: It's just for testing.
If not elevated, no folder will be created.
If elevated, later the created folder will be deleted.

Comment: Why are you saying that **IsUserAnAdmin()** is deprecated ? I didn't find a confirmation of such deprecation. The doc describe it as a "wrapper for CheckTokenMembership."

Comment: @Bemipefe It's in the Deprecated Shell APIs section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/deprecated-api. It could be superseded by newer APIs (*`IsUserAnAdmin` is available for use in the operating systems specified in the Requirements section. **It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions**.*).

Answer (score -1):

You find the answer in the MSDN:

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/118626

Also your application should have a manifest.

Comment: I get this error:

error: main must return int
void main(int argc, char **argv)

Comment: @Pawan Replace `void` with `int` on that line. `main` *must* return `int` :)

Comment: To prevent link rot, please include the essence of the solution inside the answer here :)

Comment: @MagnusHoff

Now I get the error:

undefined reference to IsCurrentUserLocalAdministrator()

Comment: @Pawan Please research your new problem and see if you can find a solution. If not, you are free to ask a new question with the "Ask Question"-button :)

Comment: As Magnus Hoff wrote: This are standard queries to C/C++ and Windows API programming. Please read some tutorials.

Comment: I did research and got nothing!

Comment: You could have spent the time to post the solution rather than the link to the solution.